# read entire fb ad account structure

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

v2.5 (Using java to implement http/json rest layer)

What is the most efficient way to read the entire structure of an FB ad account, by which I mean, all the entailed campaigns, adsets, ads and ad creatives?

Here is one way, which as a relative newcomer, I assume not to be the most efficient way. This is kind of a breadth first crawl:

- read the account data, eg., act_123?fields=id,name,owner...
- read the campaign data, eg., act_123/campaigns?fields=id,name...
- for each campaign, read the adSet data
- for each adSet, read the ad data
- for each ad, read the ad creative data

I'm thinking that those of you who've been at this a while and need to do something similar have figured out the best strategy to do this in a time efficient manner while staying on good terms with FB server servicing the API calls (avoid limits, too many calls in too short a time, etc).

Even if the entire account structure must be crawled, perhaps going depth first is better than bread first, IOW, for each campaign, request the campaign data (using a nested fields param), to fetch the adSet data, the ad Data, etc.?

Any tips, advice or guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding staying on good terms with the fb servers: The cost for your api calls are not constant but depends on the complexity of the call. So making many calls should not be more expensive in that sense than retrieving everything in one big call.

I also think that the way you do it is the way it is supposed to be done. You could get all your creatives directly on the adaccount level for example. But not fetch the entire hierarchy as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

there is a java sdk released by Facebook recently (still Beta) but you might find further information there.

I'm actually looking answer for this issue.